# Access violation reading location during realloc

Tags: c, memory, access-violation

I have the length of an array, and two float dynamic arrays.

```
int arraysizeX_right_ref = 0;
float* X_right_ref = 0;
float* Y_right_ref = 0;
int tolerance = 19;
```

grabResult.SizeX = 1440

grabResult.SizeY = 1080

I have this code below in a double for cycle. When the variable `arraysizeX_right_ref` reaches the value 303, the first line gives me the error: `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF68598FBEF in SimpleGrab.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000014DAA644000`

```
for (l = 845 + tolerance+1; l < grabResult.SizeX; l++) {
    for (j = grabResult.SizeY; j > -1; j--) {
        if (*(img + j * grabResult.SizeX + l) == 0) {
            X_right_ref = realloc(X_right_ref, ++arraysizeX_right_ref * sizeof(*X_right_ref));
            Y_right_ref = realloc(Y_right_ref, arraysizeX_right_ref * sizeof(*Y_right_ref));
            X_right_ref[arraysizeX_right_ref - 1] = l;
            Y_right_ref[arraysizeX_right_ref - 1] = j;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm guessting it stops even before incrementing `++arraySizeX_right_ref`, because `X_right_ref[302]`, that is `X_right_ref[303-1]` has an expectable value (and so does `Y_right_ref[302]`).

What's happening?

**PS: I might've induced everybody in an error(?), not sure. The error symbol, in VisualStudio, actually appears in front of the `if`, right before those reallocs. Now I'm guessing the problem is accessing** **`*img`.**

Comment: The `realloc` function can fail and return a null pointer. You need to check for that. Also, the old memory is still valid if `realloc` fails, but your assignment back to the same pointer passed to `realloc` means you loose the original (still valid) pointer and have a memory leak.

Comment: @ATSlooking4things Why is there in the first call of realloc used  ++arraysizeX_right_ref while on the second call of realloc  arraysizeX_right_ref without incrementing?

Comment: If you need more help in debugging, then please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: You're probably writing out of bounds of allocated memory somewhere in some code you didn't show. Show a [mcve].

Comment: @VladfromMoscow well, why should I increment it aswell? In the first call, I'm reallocating 
 **X**_right_ref, increasing its size. In the second call, I'm reallocating **Y**_right_ref, to have the same size as the newly incremented **X**_right_ref. Am I missing something? Notice that the "size" variable used is the same `arraysizeX_right_ref`

Comment: The name `arraysizeX_right_ref` is misleading with that `X` in it. For casual readers (like us) that make it seem like its for the `X_right_ref` array *only*, and not for anything related to `Y_right_ref`. Perhaps you should rename it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will update to include the realloc fail-safe. I provided a bit more code, so I'm guessing that if you read a 1440x1080 matrix (with values ranging from 0 to 255 = greyscale .bmp), and get it pointed by `img`, it should reproduce my code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh, I understand why you thought it was wrong. It's just to not have another variable, since it's basically just a control variable, and both arrays should always have the same size. I could take out that **X** definitely.

Comment: @ATSlooking4things A was not attentive. I thought that there is used another variable like  arraysizeY_right_ref.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow no problem, I should've named it better too :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I might've induced everybody in an error(?), not sure. The error symbol, in VisualStudio, actually appears in front of the `if`, right before those reallocs. Now I'm guessing the problem is accessing *img. I'm very sorry if that's the case.

Comment: Very likely you have the wrong types of the function parameters.

Comment: `for (j = grabResult.SizeY; j > -1; j--)` if `grabResult.SizeY = 1080` will iterate 1081 times. Is that what you [want](https://godbolt.org/z/9qYPv4Ez8)?

Comment: @Bob__ of course. Jesus, you're right. And I've made everyone waste time with a dumb error like that. Should've known better by now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bob__ can you answer so I can close this? Otherwise will just delete it. I mislead everyone, right from the title

Comment: @ATSlooking4things Well, we live and we learn... Programming is fun that way, we never stop learning. :)

Comment: I can't now, but note that what's pointed out in the current answer is important too.

Comment: @Bob__ I'll update the whole program to check for reallocs, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the correct type for sizes.
2. **Check if the `realloc` did not fail. You need to use a temporary pointer.**
3. ++something in the function call looks hacky and cool - but it is hard to read and it is error-prone. Do not save the keyboard. People used to save the paper (40y ago) as all programs were printed on paper and numbers lines could matter.

```
size_t addValue(float **x, size_t size, float j)
{
    float *tmp = realloc(*x, (size + 1) * sizeof(**x));
    if(tmp) 
    {
        *x = tmp;
        tmp[size] = j;
        size += 1;
    }

    return size;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t arraysizeX_right_ref = 0;
    size_t arraysizeY_right_ref = 0;
    float *X_right_ref = NULL;
    float *Y_right_ref = NULL;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++)
    {
        size_t newsize = addValue(&X_right_ref, arraysizeX_right_ref, 10.0f);
        if(newsize == arraysizeX_right_ref) { printf("Xarray allocation error\n"); return 1;}
        else arraysizeX_right_ref = newsize;
        newsize = addValue(&Y_right_ref, arraysizeY_right_ref, 5.0f);
        if(newsize == arraysizeY_right_ref) { printf("Yarray allocation error\n"); return 1;}
        else arraysizeY_right_ref = newsize;
    }
    printf("All was good\n");
    free(X_right_ref);
    free(Y_right_ref); 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/os6eTqbn6

Comment: I might've induced everybody in an error(?), not sure. The error symbol, in VisualStudio, actually appears in front of the `if`, right before those reallocs. Now I'm guessing the problem is accessing `*img`. Because I just replaced my code with yours, and the exact same keeps happening, without any printed message or return.